# Bitcoin extortion threat for address 14poC1Jg97vuvsyoKSZYz7h276LoAZcrtn?

Tags: malware, ransomware

I have received an email saying my computer was hacked a long time ago with a threat of realeasing personal details unless I pay a ransom to a bit coin address: 14poC1Jg97vuvsyoKSZYz7h276LoAZcrtn

Is there any way to check if the this is a hoax?

Answer (score 3):

It is a well-known hoax, ignore it.

https://blog.malwarebytes.com/cybercrime/2019/02/sextortion-bitcoin-scam-makes-unwelcome-return/

It never hurts to check your antivirus protection is up to date and that you have offline backups of important documents/photos etc (and test that you can recover from those backups)

It doesn't hurt to reconsider how you compose and use your passwords for online services (shopping banks, email, amazon, ebay, etc). Change passwords associated with websites that have had a data-breach. make sure you don't use the same password for more than one website. Make sure you use strong passwords (e.g. long random ones generated by a carefully researched and carefully chosen *reputable* password manager)

Answer (score 0):

The address has been reported 92 times to the Bitcoin Abuse Database:
https://www.bitcoinabuse.com/reports/14poC1Jg97vuvsyoKSZYz7h276LoAZcrtn

Please consider adding yours as well so others know this is nothing to worry about.